# IOS 5 : Making AppDelegate.h, an extension of UIViewController instead of NSObject or UIResponder

Tags: ios

I am trying to populate a Grouped Table View by code itself in AppDelegate and further trying to navigate to another view by making a cell UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator.

I have changed AppDelegate's extension to UINavigationController, so that I can easily move on by clicking a cell to another view. Grouped table is coming fine, but on clicking a cell it's not showing up the view. Can someone assist me by watching the code. And also please tell me the reason why AppDelegate is kept as NSObject or UIResponder as default. Here is the code

.h

```
    @interface AppDelegate : UINavigationController <UIApplicationDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>
```

.m

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath
*)indexPath
{
SecScreen *secScreen = [[SecScreen alloc] initWithNibName:@"SecScreen" bundle:nil];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:secScreen animated:YES];
[secScreen release];

}
```

Comment: It'd be better to use the term *subclass* instead of *extension* here.

Comment: yea I am newbie to objective C..I used to do blackberry code earlier..thanks for correction..:)

Answer (score 2):

I think you are confusing the function of several key UIKit components in what you are trying to do.

Every app has an application delegate object that handles events that relate to starting and stopping of the app.  The app delegate contains a reference to your app's UIWindow object and is responsible for setting the initial view controller in the window when the app launches.  Since you are creating a navigation-based app, you want the initial view controller to be a UINavigationController.  Your App Delegate class should not inherit from UINavigationController.  Instead the App Delegate should instantiate an instance of UINavigationController in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` and set that as the root view controller.

Secondly, the navigation controller's role is a container for other view controllers.  It will also handle the user's navigation between these other viewControllers.  So your tableview should not be a property of your navigationController, but instead should be a property of some custom view controller that you create.  Your custom view controller will probably inherit from UITableViewController.

You could do this all in code if you wish.  Doing it with a storyboard would be even easier though.

In code, it would look like this:

AppDelegate.h

```
@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;
@property (strong, nonatomic) UINavigationController *navigationController;
```

AppDelegate.m

```
@implementation AppDelegate

@synthesize window = _window; 
@synthesize navigationController = _viewController;

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];

    MyCustomTableViewController *tableViewController = [[MyCustomTableViewController alloc] init];    

    self.navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:tableViewController];

    self.window.rootViewController = self.navigationController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES; 
}
```

MyCustomTableViewController.h

```
@interface MyCustomTableViewController : UITableViewController
@end
```

MyCustomTableViewController.m

```
@implementation MyCustomTableViewController

 // implement usual UITableViewDelegate and UITableViewDataSource methods here ...

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath
*)indexPath
{
    SecScreen *secScreen = [[SecScreen alloc] initWithNibName:@"SecScreen" bundle:nil];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:secScreen animated:YES];
    [secScreen release];
}
```

Hope that explanation helps some!

Comment: Thanks Jon, your explanation about AppDelegate and diff between NavVC & UITabVC were very useful. I understand the way you coded my desired UI, the same long way i did earlier. I just wanted to wrap the things off in already present AppDelegate File (.h, .m) files. But my way seems unhealthy in terms of UIKit basics. I'll follow the same suggested by you. And one more thing as you have imposed navigationController as the rootVC of window, could we do the same to any of the UIView object I am working with. I mean Can we use rootViewController property with other UIView objects like window?

Comment: Please read the issue below Jon, i have mistakenly posted it as Answer, I used your way but my application crashes.

Answer (score 1):

> And also please tell me the reason why AppDelegate is kept as NSObject
>   or UIResponder as default.

It's a good idea to avoid having a single object take on multiple unrelated responsibilities. Managing the application, managing a navigation stack, and managing a view hierarchy are largely unrelated, so it makes sense to make them different classes.

> I am trying to populate a Grouped Table View by code itself in
>   AppDelegate and further trying to navigate to another view by making a
>   cell UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator.

It sounds like you're trying to do too much from a single object. Instead, you might do something like:

- Have your app delegate:

  - load whatever data you need
  - create a navigation controller and make it the window's root view controller
  - create a view controller to manage a table, give it the data it needs, and push it onto the nav controller's stack
- Use a plain old nav controller -- there's rarely a need to subclass UINavigationController
- Subclass UITableViewController to:

  - use the data it received from whoever created it (the app delegate, in this case)
  - implement `-tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` such that it creates a new view controller of the appropriate type and pushes it onto the nav stack

Comment: Thanks Caleb, Yea i was looking for the answer to my last question and you gave it reasonably well. But again my question is why NSObject or UIResponder!, is it because these Classes fall on the top in the framework hierarchy?